# Map function in JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I want to find an object from a JSON array. My code is working fine with the object found. But the issue is what if the employee id is not? My code console's "not found" two times. Kindly guide me on what the issue is with my code.

```
var E_ID

let empArray = [
 {

  "employee": {
    "employee_ID": 16,
    "employee_designation": "Node.js",
     "employee_FirstName": "John",
     "employee_lastName": "Doe",
  }
 },
 {
   "employee": {
    "employee_ID": 17,
    "employee_designation": "Full Stack",
    "employee_FirstName": "Samual",
    "employee_lastName": "Smith",
  },
 }
]

 function search_EmployeeByID(E_ID) {
  empArray.map(item => {
    if (item.employee.employee_ID == E_ID) {
         console.log(item.employee)
         return true
     
   }else {
          console.log("not found")
          return false
   }

 })

}

E_ID = parseInt(prompt("Enter Employee_ID to search for:"))
search_EmployeeByID(E_ID);`
```

Comment: find will loop over each item, until found, hence 2 times.. remove the comments, keep it simple `const result = empArray.find(item => item.employee.employee_ID === E_ID)`, no function needed

Comment: Regarding changing `find()` to `map()`, the issue is the same... it will iterate over every entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement should not be inside `find()`. `find()` will return the matching element, or `null` if it's not found. So test the return value.

```
function searchEmployeeByID(e_id) {
    let emp = empArray.find(e => e.employee.employee_ID == e_id);
    if (emp) (
        console.log(emp.employee);
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("not found");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, My task was by using a map(), find was used as I was learning to do it with find. I edited my code,

Comment: I can't think of any reasonable way to do this with `map()`. That returns a new array of the results of all the callbacks, it can't be used to select a specific element of the array.

Comment: More generally, you can't tell if the element is found during the iteration, you have to wait until the end.